# Get timestamp 23:59:59 on my date column in T SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, timestamp

I need to put timestamp 23.59.59 on my date column. Right now the format is yyyy-mm-dd.

[image: screenshot columns]

Comment: First add a day, then subtract a second.

Comment: Date time data types don't have a "format", they're a binary value. If you really are storing a format, then what you have isn't a `date`, it's a `varchar`.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

First, a "date" column does not have a time component.  So you cannot do what you want.  If you have `datetime` column you can construct the value:

```
datetimefromparts(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt), 23, 59, 59, 0)
```

However, don't do this.  This is normally needed to get the "last instant" of a day.  Instead, just change your definition of a range, so the end date is not included.  Instead of:

```
where '2020-01-01' between date_start and date_end
```

use:

```
where '2020-01-01' >= date_start and
      '2020-01-01' < date_end
```

And store `date_end` as a date *with no time component*.

Answer (score 0):

You can update date of your columns, "DATE" is your fields name.

```
UPDATE TableXYZ SET 
DATE=DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE), DAY(DATE), 23, 59, 59, 0)
WHERE ISDATE(DATE)=1
```